# static vs class as class variable/method (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I know that `static` keyword is used to declare type variable/method in `struct`, `enum` etc.

But today I found it can also be used in `class` entity.

```
class foo {
  static func hi() {
    println("hi")
  }
  class func hello() {
    println("hello")
  }
}
```

What's `static` keyword's use in `class` entity?

Thanks!

edit: I'm referring to Swift 1.2 if that makes any difference

Comment: In which version of Xcode you are trying that code ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID241?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the Xcode 3 beta 3 release notes:

> “static” methods and properties are now allowed in classes (as an
>   alias for “class final”).

So in Swift 1.2, `hi()` defined as

```
class foo {
  static func hi() {
    println("hi")
  }
}
```

is a *type method* (i.e. a method that is called on the type itself) 
which also is *final* (i.e. cannot be overridden in a subclass).

Answer (score 3):

In classes it's used for exactly the same purpose. However before Swift 1.2 (currently in beta) `static` was not available - the alternate `class` specifier was been made available for declaring static methods and computed properties, but not stored properties.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5, I use `type(of: self)` to access class properties dynamically:

```
class NetworkManager {
    private static var _maximumActiveRequests = 4
    class var maximumActiveRequests: Int {
        return _maximumActiveRequests
    }

    func printDebugData() {
        print("Maximum network requests: \(type(of: self).maximumActiveRequests).")
    }
}

class ThrottledNetworkManager: NetworkManager {
    private static var _maximumActiveRequests = 2
    override class var maximumActiveRequests: Int {
        return _maximumActiveRequests
    }
}

ThrottledNetworkManager().printDebugData()
```

Prints 2.

In Swift 5.1, we should be able to use `Self`, with a capital S, instead of `type(of:)`.