# What is the difference between static func and final class func in swift

Tags: swift

As far as I know static funcs are statically dispatched and final class funcs are also statically dispatched (since final funcs cannot be overriden - just like static funcs). But then what exactly is the difference. Is there any at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between static func and class func in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156377/what-is-the-difference-between-static-func-and-class-func-in-swift)

Comment: no.. that is class func, not final class func :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because a `final` class function can't be overridden doesn't mean it's statically dispatched. A final class function be override a superclass non-final class function. Such a method call must be dynamically dispatched.

`static` is merely an alias for `final class`. They behave the same:

```
class C1 { class func foo() {} }
class C2: C1 { override final class func foo() {} }
class C3: C1 { override static func foo() {} }
```

Comment: Yes correct, I found this after asking the question... thanks bro

Comment: "Static" is an alias for "final class": https://stackoverflow.com/a/29206635/1187415, so there should be no difference.

Comment: Intersting! they can override parent class methods, too!

Comment: So both static and final class functions can be safely concluded to be Statically dispatched

Comment: @angshuknag No, they're both dynamically dispatched. Otherwise, how would overloading work?