# Swift StaticFunction vs Java StaticFunction , is identifier needed in function declaration?

Tags: java, swift, function, static

Java:

```java
public Static int myFunction(int n){
    ...
}
```

Swift:

```swift
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"
print(str)

Static func (n: Int) -> Intdo {
    
}
```

xcode issues these:
Use of unresolved identifier 'Static'
Top-level statement cannot begin with a closure expression
Expected identifier in function declaration
Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
Did you mean to use a 'do' statement?
Closure expression is unused

Comment: You seemed to have answered your own question. Given all these errors, do you really think you can do `Static func (n:Int)->Intdo {` (whatever that is)?

Comment: not helpful, but this link was absolute help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636633/static-vs-class-functions-variables-in-swift-classes

Comment: None of the keywords in Swift or Java start with a capital. It's `static`, not `Static`. Your Java code isn't valid, either. Also, your swift function lacks a name, which is invalid.

Comment: import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"
print(str)

/**
 *
*/
class foo {
  static func hi() {
    print("hi")
  }
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206465/static-vs-class-as-class-variable-method-swift/29206635#29206635

Comment: class foo {
  static func hi() {
    println("hi")
  }
}

Comment: i replace it with static, thnx Alexander( https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander )

Answer (score 0):

[static vs class as class variable/method (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206465/static-vs-class-as-class-variable-method-swift/29206635#29206635)

for adding Static before func name add a class to encapsulate the function defined as

```
class foo {
  static func hi() {
    println("hi")
  }
}
```

is a type method (i.e. a method that is called on the type itself) which also is final (i.e. cannot be overridden in a subclass).